# PDF not opening in MOTO G

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

There are multiple PDF in WebView. I am using intent to Open a PDF from url. It is working fine on all devices except MOTO

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
```

When I tested on MOTO G device (nougat) only first PDF is opening and rest all showing cannot open this PDF

I have also tried

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What are values of `url` that work and what are values of `url` that do not work?

Comment: try using FileProvider, this happens only when the compileSdkVersion is greater 23

Comment: I don't think that it is something you can do about. That is a probelm of the app, which opens PDFs.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Urls re working perfectly on browser. I tested all URL. and my compile sdk version is 25

Comment: @Manojkumar For FileProvider, I need to download the PDF and display right?

Comment: yes u need to download the pdf to the device

Comment: "Urls re working perfectly on browser" -- I did not ask that. I asked what are values of `url` that work and what are values of `url` that do not work?

Comment: @CommonsWare There are multiple no. of PDFs in one page. Any one PDF opens first time out of all URLs ending with .pdf, but after that only that PDF opens which was opened first time. None open except that one on rest of the click